# Skipping GWT compilation in Intellij-Idea 9

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea

It seems to me that since GWT 2.0's development mode runs until your project is complete there is essentially no technical reason to run the actual Java->Javascript portion of the compiler when developing.  Unfortunately in Idea 9 before your application server starts up the GWT compiler runs and the output is bundled into your .war.  The server-side .java files are (somewhat) incrementally compiled when you do an Intellij "Make" but the GWT code always does a full compile.

Without resorting to writing my own build scripts is there a way to have Intellij not compile GWT code when I am developing and instead rely only on development mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GWT Run configuration to start GWT in Dev Mode. In such case IDEA will not build war file so GWT compiler won't run.

Comment: But then my application server (Tomcat) will not be started.

Comment: Why do you need to start Tomcat? Dev Mode uses embedded Jetty server instance.